# Expand polynomial series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Expand $f(x)=\arccos(1-2x^2)$ to polynomial series at $x_0 = 0$ and find its convergence radius. Can you provide any ideas? The main problem is that the argument does not go to $0$ when $x$ goes to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f(\sin\theta) = \arccos(\cos 2\theta) = 2|\theta|$, hence $f(x)=2\arcsin|x|$, that is not a differentiable function at the origin, hence the problem makes no sense, since there is no Taylor expansion at $x=0$.

Anyway, the Taylor series of $g(x)=\arcsin(x)$ can be easily derived from the Taylor series of its derivative $g'(x)=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$, that we may compute through the extended binomial theorem:
$$ g'(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{4^n} $$
leads to:
$$ \arcsin(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)4^n} $$
whose radius of convergence is $1$, of course. You may reach the same conclusion by using the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem): $\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\sin^n(x)\right|_{x=0}$ is fairly easy to compute through $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and the binomial theorem, again.